# Creating new data frame columns derived from another

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe (atc_df) with a column called 'atc' made of fixed length strings with a fixed structure, and can be split in 5 levels of subcoding. Here is an example:

```
    prin    atc
0   Acarbosio   A10BF01
1   Aceclofenac M01AB16
2   Aciclovir   J05AB01
3   Acido acetilsalicilico  B01AC06
4   Acido alendronico   M05BA04
... ... ...
324 Voriconazolo    J02AC03
325 Zofenopril  C09AA15
326 Zofenopril + idroclorotiazide   C09BA15
327 Zolmitriptan    N02CC03
328 Zonisamide  N03AX15
```

I have a function that given an atc code would return a list of the 5 subcodes:

```
def atc_split(atc_str):
    atc1 = atc_str[0]
    atc2 = atc_str[1:3]
    atc3 = atc_str[3]
    atc4 = atc_str[4]
    atc5 = atc_str[5:7]
    return(atc1,atc2,atc3,atc4,atc5)
```

Two questions:

Is there a more efficient/elegant way of splitting the atc code into its five subcodes?

How can I best apply this function to the atc_df dataframe to add five new columns (atc1..atc5) to each row?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df_atc[[f"atc{i+1}" for i in range(5)]] = df_atc["atc"].str.extract("(\w)(\d{2})(\w)(\w)(\d{2})")

>>> df_atc
                     prin      atc atc1 atc2 atc3 atc4 atc5
0               Acarbosio  A10BF01    A   10    B    F   01
1             Aceclofenac  M01AB16    M   01    A    B   16
2               Aciclovir  J05AB01    J   05    A    B   01
3  Acido acetilsalicilico  B01AC06    B   01    A    C   06
4       Acido alendronico  M05BA04    M   05    B    A   04
```

If you want to have every code including the previous codes, you can slice using `.str`:

```
df_atc["atc1"] = df_atc["atc"].str[0]
df_atc["atc2"] = df_atc["atc"].str[:3]
df_atc["atc3"] = df_atc["atc"].str[:4]
df_atc["atc4"] = df_atc["atc"].str[:5]
df_atc["atc5"] = df_atc["atc"]

>>> df_atc
                     prin      atc atc1 atc2  atc3   atc4     atc5
0               Acarbosio  A10BF01    A  A10  A10B  A10BF  A10BF01
1             Aceclofenac  M01AB16    M  M01  M01A  M01AB  M01AB16
2               Aciclovir  J05AB01    J  J05  J05A  J05AB  J05AB01
3  Acido acetilsalicilico  B01AC06    B  B01  B01A  B01AC  B01AC06
4       Acido alendronico  M05BA04    M  M05  M05B  M05BA  M05BA04
```

Comment: Thank you your solution works although upon further analysis I discovered that to be unique the subcodes must always include the predecessor, so for Acarbosio for instance L1=A but L2=A10, L3=A10B, L4=A10BF and L5 is all of the ATC.

Comment: I see - That's not what your function does though. In that case you could use the second approach and start every slice with `[0:]`. I've edited the second solution to demonstrate this